# The 200 daily limit isn't limiting me

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

This is my profile:

[image]

I have 839 rep.

My graph has the following: 101, 12, 217 (1 accept), 277 (5 accepts), 230 (2 upvotes):

101+12+217+277+230 = 838

so not only is it off by 1 (I remember seeing +7 for an answer - no idea how I lost that 3...) it also isn't limiting me - my rep should be 713.

101+12+200+200+200 = 713

Answer (score 4):

"Bounty awards, accepted answers [what you and most of us call 'accepts'], and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit." From the *Reputation* section of the Help page, a useful resource for such queries.

And the odd +3 comes from some combination of -2 for downvotes, +2 for accepted edits, +5 for upvotes on your questions... You can see the full history by clicking "Reputation" of your user page.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the number of accepts - each day the number of accepts is the exact number my rep execed the limit:

Day 1 (217) (1 accept, and 1 edit accepted).
Day 2 (277) (5 accepts, and 1 edit accepted).
Day 3 (230) (2 accepts, 0 edit accepted).

Comment: That's right: accepts don't count toward the 200-pt limit.